# Plot a heat map with a gradient for the tiles based on the proximity of a specific area of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-tile

My goal is to use a heat map to plot the data below. I have obtained the layout of the heat map I wanted, but I am struggling to find a way to color the tiles as intended. My guess is that the code below colors the tiles proportional to the number inside the tile itself. However, this is not what I need. I would like to:

1. have the same color within each of the rectangles (yellow for the rectangle on the left and blue for the rectangle on the right);
2. a gradient from yellow to blue for the other tiles proportional to how far away the tiles are from the blue area.

Thanks to anyone who will help!

```
library(tidyverse)

# First, I create the simulated dataset with 200 individuals
set.seed(1243)  # set seed for reproducibility

#I simulate test 1 scores
test1_score <- sample(c(3.5, 3.8, 4), 200, replace = TRUE)

#I simulate test 2 scores
test2_score <- round(runif(200, 0, 38))

#I create diagnostic classes based on test 2 scores
test2_class <- ifelse(test2_score < 20, "non meet",
                      ifelse(test2_score < 30, "below 40th",
                             ifelse(test2_score < 35, "above 40th",
                                    ifelse(test2_score < 37, "meet", "master"))))

#I create exit_program variable based on test 1 scorea and test 2 classes
exit_program <- ifelse(test1_score == 4 & test2_class %in% c("above 40th", "meet", "master"), 1, 0)

#I create data frame with simulated data
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:200, test1_score, test2_class, exit_program)

#I calculate the group size for each combination of test 1 scores and test 2 classes
df2 <- df |>
  group_by(test1_score, test2_class, exit_program) |> 
  summarize(n = n()) |> 
  mutate(test2_class = factor(test2_class, levels = c("non meet", "below 40th", "above 40th", "meet", "master"))) |> arrange(test2_class)

#plot data
df2 |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = test2_class, y = as.factor(test1_score))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12), axis.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 7, family = "sans") +
  labs(x = "classification", y = "scores", size = 10) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#56B4E9", high = "#F0E442", guide = "none") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 2.5, xmax = 5.5, ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5), linewidth = 2, color = "#0072B2", fill = NA) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 3.5), linewidth = 2, color = "#E69F00", fill = NA)
```

[image: ggplot output]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. You are right. Mapping `n` on `fill` means to color the tiles by the value of `n`.

As I understand the question you want each "column" to have the same color and colored with a gradient from  yellow on the left to blue on the right. To this end you could add a column with a measure of the distance from the left or the right end to your data which could then be mapped on the `fill` aes. One option would be to convert your `test2_class` to a numeric then compute the absolute distance from the maximum value (which corresponds to the "master" level).

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df2 |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(
    fill = as.numeric(test2_class),
    fill = abs(fill - max(fill))
  )

#plot data
df2 |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = test2_class, y = as.factor(test1_score))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12), axis.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = fill)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 7, family = "sans") +
  labs(x = "classification", y = "scores", size = 10) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#56B4E9", high = "#F0E442", guide = "none") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 2.5, xmax = 5.5, ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5), linewidth = 2, color = "#0072B2", fill = NA) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 3.5), linewidth = 2, color = "#E69F00", fill = NA)
```

[image]